# Start background jobs using Pycharm when starting server

Tags: windows-7, pycharm

I develop my python applications with Pycharm and I love it. Recently, I discovered `grunt` and  the superb `watch`-action of grunt.

I want to start `grunt watch`, and maybe some other applications, **in the background** when I start my Django server using `run`. I know, how to start applications *before launch* but Pycharm waits for their exit before starting the django server. So this is not the right way, because I need the application to run in the background.

Any ideads how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup an external tool as a launcher for the background task.

I am currently on mac, hopefully you can adapt the idea with some `dos` commands. Let's assume the background task can be started from `task.py`

**Step 1**: Create a "launcher script", saved as `bg_run.sh` in this example. Note the fork instruction `&` to run the task in a new process.

```
run_task() {
    python /Path/To/Task/task.py
}

run_task &
```

**Step 2**: Create an external tool in `Preferences` | `Tools` | `External Tools` to run that script.

[image: external tool pycharm]

**Step 3**: Add that external tool to run `before launch` in the `Run/Debug Configurations`.

**Note**: The question on how to kill that background task is left open ;)

Comment: Most likely you can also implement a similar 'fork' mechanism using another python script before launch.